# CouchBase Replication Error to Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, couchbase, elasticsearch-plugin

I have an existing replication in Couchbase -> ElasticSearch. I found out that there is now errors in replicating:

[image]

I tried to CREATE Replication again but it also gave the same error:
[image]

I already checked my elasticsearch plugin_head and I can see data in there and I can query with results. I restarted also my elasticsearch batch file but still error is persistent.
Anyone can help me on what else I need to check to further investigate the issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have a connectivity problem, which can happen due to networking issues like an IP address change since you initially setup the replication.

You might try the troubleshooting steps outlined here if you haven't already:
http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.1/connectors/elasticsearch-2.1/trouble-intro.html

You should also check the goxdcr logs, which you can find here depending on the OS you're using:
http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-logs.html

Comment: Yes, there was indeed a connectivity problem and elasticsearch ip has changed.